# FluidSynth Integration in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, midi

I was able to create a static library out of the FluidSynth source code using http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fluidsynth/wiki/FluidSynthOnIphone. Using that library, my iOS project compiles flawlessly. However I am stuck on making the it sound. I believe what is missing is a supported audio driver needed for FluidSynth to function correctly.

What I'm looking for I think is this http://fluidsynth.sourceforge.net/api/index.html#UsingSynth but I can't find helpful source code around the web about it. I imagine connecting FluidSynth with one of IOS' native audio frameworks like AudioUnit or OpenAL. Can anyone help, I understand little about buffers and stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Does iOS support MIDI?... I mean, you would need soundfonts otherwise, or not?

Answer (score 3):

I have patched FluidSynth1.0.9 as an iOS version, it contains a 'README-iOS' text file and an iOS directory which has one demo project in it.

You can download it from http://www.artgolf.info/fluidsynth-1.0.9.zip
, Have fun:)

Comment: Hi did you publish this somewhere on GitHub to take a look ?

Comment: So (of course), link is now broken

Answer (score 0):

I've made an Xcode project for iOS at https://github.com/DominusExult/fluidsynth-sans-glib/tree/sans_glib

This uses a patch by someone else to build current FluidSynth without GLib. The Xcode project(s) use FluidSynth' SDL2 audio driver.

Tested this with Exult's iOS port https://github.com/exult/exult